# Subdomain or a different domain ? What should I use

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have my personal website at www.yassershaikh.com, now I am planning to setup a website for interview related questions and answers,

Now for this I have two options

1. Using sub domain www.interview.yassershaikh.com
2. using a completely different domain www.abcdxyz.com

Now I wanted to which of the above two methods is better.

Will using sub domain hurt my SEO result ? and google ranking ?

Also I was looking for sub domain as my current site is hosted by a very good service provider and at very resonable rate, so in that way I wont have to shell out again for another domain.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a subdomain should not affect your google ranking.  A sub domain is cheaper, provided you have a way to host the DNS records without paying somebody else anything extra.  Keep in mind that you can also use interview.yassershaikh.com -- you don't need the leading www.  As a matter of fact, you don't even need a subdomain; all you need is another hostname.  Right now you have an 'A' record, a hostname, at www.yassershaikh.com.  You can create another 'A' record at interview.yassershaikh.com, and use that.  Google doesn't care whether your host is named www.yassershaikh.com, interview.yassershaikh.com, or bluecheese.yassershaikh.com -- you can have a bunch of them, all directly under the yassershaikh.com domain.

Comment: hi i have configured a sub domain at "http://interview.yassershaikh.com" now is that the same thing you mentioned "provided you have a way to host the DNS records without paying somebody else anything extra" ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant, even if I didn't say it very well.  I've now fixed my answer to clarify the fact that you don't even need a subdomain, just another hostname, an 'A' record, like you now have.  From here it looks like interview.yassershaikh.com is working -- I see the polymorphism/inheritance/abstraction sections etc. on that page.  ;-)